# Class resource_model_resource mapper not found in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have redirected to resource module from indexController using following code:

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoSimple('view-resource', 'Resource', 'Resource', array());
```

where view-resource is action and Resource is controller and Resource is module.it is redirecting correctly.Now in view-resource action I have following code:

```
public function viewResourceAction()
{
    $region=new Resource_Model_ResourceMapper();
}
```

Now error occurs as Resource_Model_ResourceMapper not found.Why this??When I check .zfproject,It contains the mapping of Resource module and it specifies as

```
<controllerFile controllerName="Resource"> <actionMethod actionName="index"/>       <actionMethodactionName="viewResource"/> 
<modelFile modelName="ResourceMapper"/>
```

That means it should recognize ResourceMapper but it does not find why??

My second question is:------ If I want to delete any action then it has to be deleted manually in .zfproject file. There should be some command,shouldnt be??
Thanks

Comment: Plz answer.I need to know this immediately

Comment: The `.zfproject.xml` file actually has no impact on how the project runs. I believe it is used purely by as a kind-of manifest for `Zend_Tool`. For example, nearly all my Zend Framework projects have no `.zfproject.xml` file. What is the path for the file containing the class `Resource_Model_ResourceMapper`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `resource` module contains a Bootstrap.php with a class `Resource_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {}`

In your application.ini you at least need to have `resources.modules[] =`

The modules resource (`Zend_Application_Resource_Modules`) is responsible for creating instances of each module bootstrap class. Each module bootstrap class will create a module autoloader (`Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader`), responsible for autoloading the module based classes like `Resource_Form_A`, `Resource_Model_B` and  `Resource_Service_C`.

To answer your second question; Zend_Tool is extremely limited in its usage. To maintain .zfproject.xml you have to do most of it by hand. In my opinion there are no real benefits for using Zend_Tool to create and maintain your project. Now worth the trouble.